# How to run mist on mac os

Tags: contract-development, mist

I am very new to Ethereum dev and I am currently following a tutorial. However, the Remix IDE seems a bit different from the one on my computer, likely because Mist has updated since the tutorial has been uploaded. 
Basically, I don't know how to compile and run my code. 

I tried the create button under "run" on the right navigation bar. This is the error message I am getting:
creation of MyFirstContract errored: Send transaction failed: invalid address . if you use an injected provider, please check it is properly unlocked.
I don't know if this is useful but my mist is set to the Rinkeby test network.

It would be really appreciated if someone could teach me how I can run my code. :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your web3 provider in the settings tab to "Javascript VM" and it should solve your issue.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to find a place to change my "web3 provider" under the settings tab. Any further instructions?

Comment: Whoops my apologies it's in the `Run` tab.  where it says 'environment' you want ot select the javascriptVM

Comment: I'm guessing you're referring to Remix's web3 provider?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [Mist](https://github.com/ethereum/mist) has been deprecated. I recommend using [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) for deploying smart contracts, and [MetaMask](https://metamask.io) for interacting with DApps.